# How to create a Carbon date in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, php-carbon

How do you I create a Carbon date if I have the date part in the following format 'd M Y' and I have hours and minutes in separate variables as integers.

eg.

```
$this->start_dt  = '06 Feb 2016'
$this->start_hr  = '12'
$this->start_min  = '00'
```

Currently I'm having to do this but it also ends up adding the current seconds.

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('d M Y', $this->start_dt)->hour($this->start_hr)->minute($this->start_min);
```

result `2016-02-06 12:00:44`

Is there a more cleaner way to create a carbon date without having to chain the hours and minutes and to set the seconds to 00?

Maybe something like this but it doesn't work:

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('d M Y H:i', $this->start_dt, $this->start_hr, $this->start_min);
```

*** UPDATE ***

Manage to figure out:

```
 Carbon::createFromFormat('d M Y H:i:s', $this->start_dt . ' ' . $this->start_hr . ':'. $this->start_min . ':00');
```

Comment: Can't you just add seconds as you want?

Comment: Heh yeah like your edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documentation: Instantiation](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-instantiation)

```
Carbon::createFromDate($year, $month, $day, $tz);
Carbon::createFromTime($hour, $minute, $second, $tz);
Carbon::create($year, $month, $day, $hour, $minute, $second, $tz);
```

[Documentation: Fluent setters](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-settersfluent)

```
$dt->year(1975)->month(5)->day(21)->hour(22)->minute(32)->second(5)->toDateTimeString();
$dt->setDate(1975, 5, 21)->setTime(22, 32, 5)->toDateTimeString();
$dt->setDateTime(1975, 5, 21, 22, 32, 5)->toDateTimeString();
```

Solution:

```
Carbon::createFromFormat('d M Y', $this->start_dt)
    ->setTime($this->start_hr, $this->start_min);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use createFromFormat than you have to inout the second argument as a string like this :

```
$dt=Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d M Y H:i', $this->start_dt.' '.$this->start_hr.':'.$this->start_min);
```